# Parse JSON from HttpURLConnection object

Tags: java, html, json, parsing, httpurlconnection

I am doing basic http auth with the `HttpURLConnection` object in Java.

```
        URL urlUse = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlUse.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        conn.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        conn.connect();

        if(conn.getResponseCode()==201 || conn.getResponseCode()==200)
        {
            success = true;
        }
```

I am expecting a JSON object, or string data in the format of a valid JSON object, or HTML with simple plain text that is valid JSON. How do I access that from the `HttpURLConnection` after it returns a response?

Comment: Note that all 2xx HTTP status codes indicates success.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can get raw data using below method. BTW, this pattern is for Java 6. If you are using Java 7 or newer, please consider [try-with-resources pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
       if (c != null) {
          try {
              c.disconnect();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then you can use returned string with [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to map JSON to object of specified class, like this:

```
String data = getJSON("http://localhost/authmanager.php");
AuthMsg msg = new Gson().fromJson(data, AuthMsg.class);
System.out.println(msg);
```

There is a sample of AuthMsg class:

```
public class AuthMsg {
    private int code;
    private String message;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

JSON returned by http://localhost/authmanager.php must look like this:

```
{"code":1,"message":"Logged in"}
```

Regards

Comment: Can I ask you, where you close the connection `c`?

Comment: Originally I wrote this in java 7 manner with try-with-resources, but someone decided to keep java 6, so connection closing was ignored finally. But yes, connection must be closed. I'll edit this later, thanks.

Comment: @kbec I still do not see where you close the connection. Could you please add this to your answer?

Comment: @kbec HttpURLConnection has no close did you mean ``disconnect()``?

Comment: Maybe, catching MalformedURLException is useless since there is already IOException ?

Comment: If you don't want to distinguish that exceptions then yes - it's useless.

Comment: fromJson() is a non-static method, fix the answer

Comment: Should getJson() method not return sb?

Comment: getJson() can even return ByteBuffer if you want

Comment: You don't handle response encoding.

Comment: You can handle encoding by second InputStreamReader parameter. This is just an example, not a production code.

Answer (score 11):

Define the following function (not mine, not sure where I found it long ago):

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

}

Then:

```
String jsonReply;
if(conn.getResponseCode()==201 || conn.getResponseCode()==200)
    {
        success = true;
        InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();
        jsonReply = convertStreamToString(response);

        // Do JSON handling here....
    }
```

Comment: `convertStreamToString` doesn't notify the calling code that the string is incomplete if a connection is lost mid-transfer. Generally, it is better to let the exceptions bubble up.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, if you wish to parse your object in case of http error (400-5** codes),
You can use the following code: (just replace  'getInputStream' with 'getErrorStream':

```
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

The JSON string will just be the body of the response you get back from the URL you have called. So add this code

```
...
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

That will allow you to see the JSON being returned to the console. The only missing piece you then have is using a JSON library to read that data and provide you with a Java representation.

[Here's an example using JSON-LIB](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/)

Comment: The input buffer doesn't get closed if there is an exception reading the input.

Answer (score 0):

This function will be used get the data from url in form of HttpResponse object.

```
public HttpResponse getRespose(String url, String your_auth_code){
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postForGetMethod = new HttpPost(url);
postForGetMethod.addHeader("Content-type", "Application/JSON");
postForGetMethod.addHeader("Authorization", your_auth_code);
return client.execute(postForGetMethod);
}
```

Above function is called here and we receive a String form of the json using the Apache library Class.And in following statements we try to make simple pojo out of the json we received.

```
String jsonString     =     
EntityUtils.toString(getResponse("http://echo.jsontest.com/title/ipsum/content/    blah","Your_auth_if_you_need_one").getEntity(), "UTF-8");
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(JsonJavaModel .class, new    CustomJsonDeserialiser());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
JsonJavaModel pojoModel = gson.fromJson(
                    jsonElementForJavaObject, JsonJavaModel.class);
```

This is a simple java model class for incomming json.
    public class JsonJavaModel{
    String content;
    String title;
    }
This is a custom deserialiser:

```
public class CustomJsonDeserialiserimplements JsonDeserializer<JsonJavaModel>         {

@Override
public JsonJavaModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
                                 JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws    JsonParseException {
    final JsonJavaModel jsonJavaModel= new JsonJavaModel();
    JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();

    try {
     jsonJavaModel.content = object.get("Content").getAsString()
     jsonJavaModel.title = object.get("Title").getAsString()

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonJavaModel;
}
```

Include Gson library and org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;