# Get a key value from the JSON response of JAVA rest api call

Tags: java, json

I have rest call and I want to get one of the key values from the JSON response, for example the value of "employeeID".

This is the code for the rest call:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;



public class App {

public static String username = "Test_Username";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

        try {
            URL url = new URL ("http://api.com/" + username);
            String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(":".getBytes("utf-8"));

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in   = 
                new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));   
         String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a sample of the JSON response:

```
[{
    "user": {
        "userID": "Adam555",
        "name": "Test Account",
        "id": 1055287,
        "recentApps": null,
        "employeeID": "2991KDS"
    },
    "user_state": {
        "EmployeeLookUpDBId": 1055304,
        "userID": "Adam555",
        "username": "Adam555"}]
```

So how can I get it in System.out.println for example saying "2991KDS"?

Comment: Doesn't this solve your problem? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500775/parse-json-from-httpurlconnection-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500775/parse-json-from-httpurlconnection-object)

Comment: @crocarneiro unfortunately no, I want to get a single value only, not the whole JSON response.
I already get the response successfully, I just want to extract a single value from the response.

Comment: @AdamAyman After you parse the JSON response it is very easy to extract any value from the JSON response. Please search on google "How to use JSON response in Java" instead of posting on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Import this library your pom.xml file

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20200518</version>
</dependency>
`

`
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class App {

  public static String username = "Test_Username";

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {
      URL url = new URL ("http://api.com/" + username );
      String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(":".getBytes("utf-8"));

      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
      InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
      JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(content);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);

        System.out.println(json.getJSONObject("user").get("employeeID"));

    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's getting close, I have now only small issue it's throwing an error because the JSON response starts with [{

I tried to replace [ with "" but no luck so far. @Chabo

Comment: @AdamAyman what is the structure of your JSON? Because that will determine how we access the fields.

Comment: @AdamAyman check my update. 
`{
    "user": {
        "userID": "Adam555",
        "name": "Test Account",
        "id": 1055287,
        "recentApps": null,
        "employeeID": "2991KDS"
    },
    "user_state": {
        "EmployeeLookUpDBId": 1055304,
        "userID": "Adam555",
        "username": "Adam555"}
}`

Comment: This is my structure it's starting with [   which is causing the problem

`[{
    "user": {
        "userID": "Adam555",
        "name": "Test Account",
        "id": 1055287,
        "recentApps": null,
        "employeeID": "2991KDS"
    },
    "user_state": {
        "EmployeeLookUpDBId": 1055304,
        "userID": "Adam555",
        "username": "Adam555"}]`

Comment: @AdamAyman That is not a valid JSON format

Comment: unfortunately this is how the response is coming and I cannot change it. 

Isn't it possible to replace the [ with nothing before  ` JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(content);` ?

Comment: Try replace method on String JSON before parsing it .replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

Comment: I tried below but didn't help or am I doing it wrong?

`JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(content).replace("[", "").replace("]", "");`

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(
          new JSONObject(tokener).toString()
              .replace("[", "")
              .replace("]", ""));

Comment: Same error "JSONObject text must begin with '{'